# Why are dates sometimes incorrect on Stack Exchange's 'Favorite Tags' view?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, dates, favorites-tab

Earlier this evening I saw a [question](https://superuser.com/questions/208898/outlook-2010-pst-not-indexing) in my 'Favorite Tags' view that sounded like it might have an interesting answer, and that said it was from **11 hours ago**:

[image]

So I decided to have a look. Once there, I decided to make a few corrections. Only, after saving the change, I had a closer look at the question, and realised that:

- It was asked on Nov 9 2010
- Its answer was added on Mar 24, 2011 - and was edited on Jul 1 2011

That is, there were no visible changes on the page from anything close to 11 hours ago.

[image]

[image]

Possibly relevant info:

- This isn't a new problem: I typically notice it several times a day: this time, curiosity just got the better of me...
- I'm using Safari on an iOS 5 iPad. I *think* it happened before the upgrade to iOS, but can't say for sure.
- I have seen [reports of problems with out-of-date cached pages on iPads since iOS5](http://www.mactalk.com.au/59/105044-safari-back-button-cached-pages.html), but I don't believe I used the Back button in this case.

**So, why did this just show up as *11 hours ago* on 'Favorite Tags'?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was bumped by [**Community ♦**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) 11 hours ago because it doesn't have an accepted / upvoted answer.